converting .raw image to 16 bit tiff
I am trying to convert .raw image to 16-bit tiff format. the raw format(.raw) that i am using does not have support from rawpy, imageio or any other librabry so i am using custom pre-processing script
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

BIT8 = 2 ** 8
BIT16 = 2 ** 16
BIT24 = 2 ** 24

class Debayer3x3(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Debayer3x3, self).__init__()
        # Initialize kernel and index parameters for debayering
        self.kernels = torch.nn.Parameter(
            torch.tensor([
                [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0.25, 0], [0.25, 0, 0.25], [0, 0.25, 0],
                [0.25, 0, 0.25], [0, 0, 0], [0.25, 0, 0.25],
                [0, 0, 0], [0.5, 0, 0.5], [0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0.5, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0.5, 0],
            ]).view(5, 1, 3, 3), requires_grad=False
        )
        self.index = torch.nn.Parameter(
            torch.tensor([
                [0, 3], [4, 2], [1, 0],
                [0, 1], [2, 4], [3, 0],
            ]).view(1, 3, 2, 2), requires_grad=False
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # Apply convolution and index gathering for debayering
        B, C, H, W = x.shape
        x = F.pad(x, (1, 1, 1, 1), mode='replicate')
        c = F.conv2d(x, self.kernels, stride=1)
        rgb = torch.gather(c, 1, self.index.repeat(B, 1, H//2, W//2))
        return rgb

def read_raw_24b(file_path, img_shape=(1, 1, 1856, 2880), read_type=np.uint8):
    # Read the raw image file into a suitable format for processing
    raw_data = np.fromfile(file_path, dtype=read_type)
    raw_data = raw_data[0::3] + raw_data[1::3] * BIT8 + raw_data[2::3] * BIT16
    raw_data = raw_data.reshape(img_shape).astype(np.float32)
    return raw_data

def white_balance(image):
    # Calculate the mean of each channel
    mean_r = image[:, :, 0].mean()
    mean_g = image[:, :, 1].mean()
    mean_b = image[:, :, 2].mean()
    
    # Adjust each channel to balance the colors
    image[:, :, 0] *= (mean_g / mean_r)
    image[:, :, 2] *= (mean_g / mean_b)
    
    return image

def func(filename, debayer, out_path, pattern='RGGB', BIT16=65535):
    # Main processing function to read, debayer, and white balance an image
    im = read_raw_24b(filename)
    print(im.shape)
    im = torch.from_numpy(im)

    # Apply the debayer process
    with torch.no_grad():
        im = debayer(im).detach().numpy()

    # Apply white balance
    im = white_balance(im).squeeze()
    im = np.transpose(im, (1, 2, 0))
    im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
    # Resize and normalize the image
    print(im.shape)
    im = cv2.resize(im, (720, 720), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    im = np.clip(im, 0, BIT16 - 1) / (BIT16 - 1)
    im = np.clip(im, 0, 1) * (BIT16 - 1)
    im = im.astype(np.uint16)

    # Save the processed image
    save_path = os.path.join(out_path, os.path.basename(filename).replace('.raw', '.tiff'))
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, im)

def main(in_path, out_path):
    # Set up directories and process each file
    assert os.path.isdir(in_path), f'Invalid input path: {in_path}'
    os.makedirs(out_path, exist_ok=True)
    files = glob(os.path.join(in_path, '*.raw'))
    debayer = Debayer3x3()

    for file_path in tqdm(files):
        func(file_path, debayer, out_path)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    in_path = '/home/singh.risha'  # Change to your raw file path
    out_path = '/home/singh.risha'  # Change to your actual output directory path

    main(in_path, out_path)

using this i am able to convert image but it done't have right colors. it looks more like green-ish image. i think there is some bug in code but i am not able to solve it. also attaching image to understand better.

A bayer filter has twice as many green pixels as red and blue ones, maybe that accounts for your problem.

[mre] required. including input data. and show your output image. you claim to be doing white balance. that should not leave your image with a green tint.

It's unclear. Describe the raw format of your image in English. Your code contains Bayer related symbols. Is this a bayer pattern such as BGGR?
